# Equivalent to "from module import (func1, func2, func3)" using importlib.util to import from arbitrary path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to do the equivalent of this python import statement

```
from module import func1, func2, func3, var1, var2, ...
```

but the module name and location are passed to the script as command line arguments, so I'm using importlib.util. Is there a more pythonic way to get the variable names into the main module's namespace?

```
import importlib.util
import sys

modulepath = sys.argv[1]
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('modulename', modulepath)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

# Is there a better way than this?
func1 = module.func1
func2 = module.func2
func3 = module.func3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about

```
from module import func1, func2, func3, var1, var2, ...
```

but you can do

```
func1, func2, func3 = module.func1, module.func2, module.func3
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in what sense you would like to have a "better" way to do it, but you could simply encapsulate your code in a function like:

```
import importlib.util

def import_from(modulename, modulepath, *names):
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(modulename, modulepath)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return tuple(getattr(module, name) for name in names)
```

Then you could just do:

```
import sys

modulepath = sys.argv[1]
func1, func2, func3 = import_from('modulename', modulepath, 'func1', 'func2', 'func3')
```